# Convert dictionary to Javascript JSON Object?

Tags: python, json, jinja2

From `views.py` I have a dictionary that is like this:

```
BgDict = {
            '1': '#031B4D', 
            '0': '', 
            '3': '#062847', 
            '2': '#303E4D', 
            '5': '#115478', 
            '4': '#00122e', 
            '7': '#152324', 
            '6': '#243447', 
            '8': '#11202F'
        }
```

I would like to convert this dict `BgDict` to Javascript Json Object in jinja2 template, so my whole code is like this

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/User/Profile/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getFormUpload():

    BgDict = {
                '1': '#031B4D', 
                '0': '', 
                '3': '#062847', 
                '2': '#303E4D', 
                '5': '#115478', 
                '4': '#00122e', 
                '7': '#152324', 
                '6': '#243447', 
                '8': '#11202F'
            }

    return render_template("profile.html",  BgDict=json.dumps(BgDict))
```

**profile.html**

```
<script>
    var bgjson = '{{BgDict|tojson|safe}}';
    console.log(jQuery.type(bgjson));
    console.log(bgjson[4]); // it should be #00122e but it is :
</script>
```

From console log, its type is `String` therefore `bgjson[4]` is `:` instead of `#00122e`.

What happened with this? How can I get `json` object out of `BgDict`? Thanks.

Comment: If you're already doing `json.dumps(...)` before passing it to the template - why do you need `|tojson` in the template itself? Looks like you want one or the other - not both. Also... don't you need a `var jsonData = JSON.parse(bgjson)` in there?

Comment: @JonClements, I just tried working around, but it still does not work even I removed `|tojson`, it was still the same. Thanks

Comment: And did you do `JSON.parse(...)` to actually make the string an object?

Comment: @JonClements, ah yeah it is,`JSON.parse(bgson)`  now I can get `json` object and its value. Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JSON.parse method

```
<script>
    var bgjson = {{BgDict|tojson|safe}};
    console.log(jQuery.type(bgjson));
    console.log(JSON.parse(bgjson)[4]);
</script>
```